# How to cast primitive types?

Tags: rust

How should I  cast primitive types in Rust?

In C-derived languages, one normally does

```
    int i = 0;
    long j = (long)i;
```

This does not work in Rust. What should I use instead?

Comment: This is described pretty well in [*The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book), specifically the chapter titled "[Casting Between Types](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/casting-between-types.html)".

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the [`as` keyword](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/casting-between-types.html#as):

```
let x: i32 = 5;
let y: u32 = x as u32;
```